# Section com duas cores

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou tendo dificuldades em fazer uma section com duas cores(uma ocupando 70% da section e a outra cor os 30% restantes), gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer isso

segue o exemplo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

sugestões?

Comment: deveria seguir o código que vc já tentou fazer também.

Comment: eu tento fazer usando divs, mas o resultado não sai como esta na imagem acima

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar um `linear-gradient()` para alcançar o efeito desejado.

> A função `linear-gradient()` do CSS cria uma imagem com consistência
>   progressiva entre duas ou mais cores ao longo de uma linha reta.

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 0, blue 70%, yellow 30%);
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Referências:

- [linear-gradient() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

Comment: Muito Obrigado! deu certo

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Só para lembrar: você pode marcar a resposta como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos da escolhida. Ou, caso queira, pode deixar em aberto mais um tempo se deseja mais alternativas de solução.